# How to call gradle task from another gradle task

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library project. This project has 2 artifacts. One is for java, and the other for Android. I am distributing these to other projects by releasing them to my local maven repository.

The android project doesn't compile directly to a jar. Instead it compiles to something maven now supports called an aar. Currently this aar file generates and is pushed to the local maven repository by me calling `./gradlew clean uploadArchives`

Here is the custom code I added to my android library project that allows for this:

```
def coreAarFile = file('build/android.aar')
artifacts {
    archives coreAarFile
}
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://" + System.getProperty('user.home') + "/.m2/repository/")
            pom.groupId = group
            pom.artifactId = 'android'
            pom.version = version
        }
    }
}
```

That works great. To release my java artifact I have to run a different command. The standard `./gradlew clean install` works fine.

**The problem is I want one command to push them both to the local maven repository. How would I go about doing this?**

Comment: Is this a single-project or multi-project build?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I'm not sure what the bounds of a project is in gradle, but I have 3 total build.gradle's. One that wraps up both the android and the java code bases, one for the android code base, and one for the java. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `gradle install` should also work for the android library project. Running it from the root project directory should install both artifacts into the local Maven repository.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser just verified that it does not. Only does the java version.

Comment: You'll need to figure out why, and fix the problem.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I think it's the fact that one uses the android-library plugin, and the other java. I think the Android plugin messes with things. I'll need to do this custom myself I think. How would I do that?

Comment: I can't find much information on publishing in the Android plugin docs, but apparently it goes together with Gradle's new "maven-publish" plugin.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for all your effort so far. I appreciate it. Surely there must be a way to call another task or group another task together with another task so they are both called by a single task.

Comment: Sure - simply declare a task that depends both on `uploadArchives` and `install`. However, using `uploadArchives` to publish to the local Maven repo is a workaround at best.